# If we know T:Borrow<Q> can we somehow force Rc<T>:Borrow<Q>?

Tags: rust

I have a container that owns the values passed to it, but internally ownership is shared between a vector and a hashmap using an `Rc`.

```
pub struct Container<T: Ord + Hash> {
    contents: Vec<Rc<T>>,
    index: HashMap<Rc<T>, usize>,
}
```

Among many methods the struct has a `contains` method which works fine:

```
pub fn contains(&self, val: &T) -> bool {
    self.index.contains_key(val)
}
```

Now I want to make `contains` more generic and accept as parameter also types that `T` can be borrowed as, for example if we have a `Container<String>`, we want `contains` to accept also `&str`:

```
pub fn contains<Q>(&self, val: &Q) -> bool
where
    T: Borrow<Q>,
    Q: Hash + Ord + ?Sized,
{
    self.index.contains_key(val)
}
```

But now the `contains_key` call inside the method doesn't compile because `Rc<T>` cannot be borrowed as `Q` even if `T` can.

How can I check the contents of the `HashMap<Rc<T>, usize>` with a `&Q' parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this isn't really something you can solve even with a newtype.

Let's assume you do have a newtype `MyRc<T>` that contains an `Rc<T>`. Based on the question you're asking, you want this implementation:

```
impl<T, U> Borrow<U> for MyRc<T> where T: Borrow<U> { ... }
```

However, there is a blanket `impl<T> Borrow<T> for T` in the standard library. The desired implementation conflicts with this blanket implementation when `T=U`, so it is disallowed.